# How to get multiple selected row index in the table in angular 13

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, angular13

I am trying to get multiple selected table row index in my code. But i am getting only one row index. So, How to get mutiple selected row index?

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lpwp3n?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

app.component.html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead></thead>
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let row of data1">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="row.isSelected"/></td>
      <td (click)="row.isExpand = !row.isExpand">
        <i *ngIf="!row.isExpand" class="bi-chevron-right"></i>
        <i *ngIf="row.isExpand" class="bi-chevron-up"></i>
        {{ row.name }}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="row.isExpand">
      <td colspan="2">
        {{ row.expandData }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

app.component.ts:

```
  addSelectedRow() {
    const selectedRowIndexFromTable1 = this.data1.findIndex(
      (row) => row.isSelected
    );
    if (selectedRowIndexFromTable1 !== -1) {
      this.data2.push({
        ...this.data1[selectedRowIndexFromTable1],
        isSelected: false,
      });
    }

    alert(selectedRowIndexFromTable1);
  }

  removeSelectedRow() {
    const selectedRowIndexFromTable2 = this.data2.findIndex(
      (row) => row.isSelected
    );
    if (selectedRowIndexFromTable2 !== -1) {
      this.data2.splice(selectedRowIndexFromTable2, 1);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `.findIndex()` only returns the first matching item. You can use a `for`-loop over the index or use `.forEach()` which provides the index as the second argument to the callback function. For adding items, you can also use `.filter()` to get all selected items.

Comment: @rveerd: I am new for angular. Can you edit my stackblitz?

Comment: @rveerd: Not able to remove multiple selected row from table 2: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-194jbu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the **addSelectedRow** function, check below code and replace the function with that.

- Probem with your code

> you are using **findIndex** method which return the index value of **first** match element and that is the reason it is only adding one record in **data2** object
>
> > convert that code into fetching multiple records with **isSelected** condition using **filter** method and insert all the records into **data2** object using loop

```
addSelectedRow() {
const selectedItems = this.data1.filter((row) => row.isSelected);
this.data2 = [];
selectedItems.forEach((item) => {
  this.data2.push({
    ...item,
    isSelected: false,
  });
});

alert(selectedItems);
}
```